# How to make this change border color animation stop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I found this code and I'm wondering how to make it stop blinking after 3 seconds

```
function flashit()
{

var myborder = document.getElementById('my');

if (myborder.style.borderColor=="green") 

myborder.style.borderColor="red" ;

else 
myborder.style.borderColor="green" ;


} 
setInterval('flashit()', 400) ;
```

Comment: Can you use CSS as an alternative?

Comment: Have you tried `setTimeout()`?

Comment: I'm trying to make it work using Javascript :) Sorry newbie here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` and `setInterval` return an identifier that refers back to the timeout/interval; which can then later be used to unset them.

So I changed your code to demonstrate. Please comment if you have any questions.

```
function flashit(){
    var myborder = document.getElementById('my');

    if (myborder.style.borderColor=="green"){
        myborder.style.borderColor="red" ;
    } else {
        myborder.style.borderColor="green" ;
    }
}
var intervalId = setInterval(flashit, 400) ;
setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vince I'm still trying to learn ;) This works like charm!

Comment: Not a problem! You're just lucky you didn't have to learn JS back in the stupid ages :p (think pre-2005)

Comment: Lol :) I hope I can  get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(flashit, 400);

// Stop after 3 seconds
setTimeout(function(){clearInterval(refreshIntervalId)}, 3000);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bys5oyre/)